# Use Variable value in longitude and latitude for Map in iOS

Tags: ios, maps, latitude-longitude

I want to add variable values in my Map longitude and latitude. My usable codes are

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
region.center.latitude = 23.804512;  //Want to the value of lats from bellow
region.center.longitude = 90.360714; //Want to the value of lons from bellow
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Variable values which I want to use.

```
NSString *lons = [self.currentphoto lon ]; // lon and lat value came exactly from previous
NSString *lats = [self.currentphoto lat ];
```

Any one help me in my issue. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Hello Mutawe, I want to add lons and lats value in my **region.center.latitude=lats** and **region.center.longitude=lons** . But how its possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the setting of `region.center.latitude` and `region.center.longitude` setter value data-type is **double** value and you are trying to set **String** Value so just do like following hope that works for you.

```
region.center.latitude     = [lats floatValue];
region.center.longitude    = [lons  floatValue];
```

**or**

```
region.center.latitude     = [lats doubleValue];
region.center.longitude    = [lons  doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *lons = [self.currentphoto lon ]; // lon and lat value came exactly from previous
    NSString *lats = [self.currentphoto lat ];

    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[lats doubleValue] longitude:[lons doubleValue]];

    region.center = location.coordinate;
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```